# Every natural number can be represented as a sum of Fibonacci numbers.

Tags: induction, fibonacci-numbers

Given:

$F_0 = 1 , F_1 = 1$, For 2 and so on $F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}$ (Fibonacci series).

Need to prove by induction:

For each natural $n$ there is a natural number $k$ and numbers:

$a_0, a_1, ..., a_k \in \{0,1\}$

So it exists:
$$n = \sum_{i=0}^{k}a_iF_i$$

Comment: I'll tell you more: they can be chosen so that $a_i+a_{i-1}<2,\;i=1,\dots,k$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeckendorf%27s_theorem